# How SSL and Certificates work between server & browser

Tags: ssl, certificate

i do not have good understanding about how SSL and Certificates work between server & browser. so i got a little write up on this from this site **http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SSL-Certificates-HOWTO/x64.html** whatever they said not very clear to me

### they said

```
1) A browser requests a secure page (usually https://).

2) The web server sends its public key with its certificate.

3) The browser checks that the certificate was issued by a trusted party 
   (usually a trusted root CA), that the certificate is still valid and that the 
   certificate is related to the site contacted.

4) The browser then uses the public key, to encrypt a random symmetric 
   encryption key and sends it to the server with the encrypted URL required 
   as well as other encrypted http data.

5) The web server decrypts the symmetric encryption key using 
   its private key and uses the symmetric key to decrypt the URL and http data.

6) The web server sends back the requested html document and 
   http data encrypted with the symmetric key.

7) The browser decrypts the http data and html document using 
   the symmetric key and displays the information.
```

### see the point 2

browser request a secure page and web server just send the public key with certificate with no page or data to browser?

if possible please discuss point regarding what happen when browser request any https page. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLS handshake happens (and is complete) before any HTTP requests are sent. And the handshake involves several messages being sent between the client and the server and back.

<s>Here's more [detailed description of SSL/TLS handshake](https://www.eldos.com/security/articles/1948.php?page=3).</s>

So any HTTP requests are sent only after the SSL/TLS layer is ready. Doing otherwise would impose a security risk.

Comment: Point 3 in your link isn't correct, and it is extremely vague about how the session key is negotiated. A public key can't be used to sign anything, and the implication that the session key is transmitted isn't correct either.

Answer (score 5):

> 1) A browser requests a secure page (usually https://).

No. The browser negotiates a TLS connection in which steps 2 and 3 and some others take place. *Then* the browser requests a secure page and step 6 happens.

> 2) The web server sends its public key with its certificate.
>
> 3) The browser checks that the certificate was issued by a trusted party 
>      (usually a trusted root CA), that the certificate is still valid and that the 
>     certificate is related to the site contacted.

OK up to here.

> 4) The browser then uses the public key, to encrypt a random symmetric 
>      encryption key and sends it to the server with the encrypted URL required 
>     as well as other encrypted http data.
>
> 5) The web server decrypts the symmetric encryption key using 
>      its private key

4 and 5 are complete fantasy, but a common delusion. What really happens is a key negotiation algorithm whose precise nature depends on the cipher suite, but which *never* involves transmitting the session key.

> and uses the symmetric key to decrypt the URL and http data.
>
> 6) The web server sends back the requested html document and 
>     http data encrypted with the symmetric key.
>
> 7) The browser decrypts the http data and html document using 
>     the symmetric key and displays the information.

Correct.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more on "whose precise nature depends on the cipher suite"?